# Using Tuples for creating the sample space

Tags: probability-or-statistics, infinite-loop, tuples, procedural-programming

I want to use `Tuples` (if you know better way please let me know) to create the sample space for some events. Assume that I have 2 events each of which can change to a known number (in the case of a coin it is 2). I want to get all of the possible combinations. Something like this:

```
{0 0} {0 1} {1 0} {1 1}
```

I can use nested for loop but prefer to not.

I used `Tuples` and `Do` (see the code below), but it does not give the right answer. What is the problem?

```
sampleSpaces = 

TableForm[Tuples[{i, j}, 2]]], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}];
```

Comment: `Table` is what you wanted here. `TableForm` is a formatting wrapper, and should not be used in these cases, only to do visual formatting.

Comment: To add to the comment by @CATrevillian there are extra brackets in the code you provided. Can you try to run `sampleSpaces = 
 Table[Tuples[{i, j, k}, 3], {i, 0, 2}, {j, 0, 2}, {k, 0, 2}]` and let us know if it works?

Comment: It creates a lot of repeated set for example, 31 of {0,0,0}. it is not what I need.

Comment: @Parviz well perhaps you could consider giving a minimal working example (MWE) with the expected outcome so the rest of us can try to help? In the way that the question is written, fixing the code you provided seems the only alternative.

Comment: `Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]`?

Comment: `RandomChoice[Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], 10]`?

Comment: just to build up to what you previously had...using the first suggestion by @cvgmt you can write `Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]` which gives `{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {1,1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}`

Answer (score 1):

Using the correct syntax for the command you give we have:

```
sampleSpaces = Table[Tuples[{i, j}, 2], {i, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 1}];
```

Then we re-arrange the list in the following manner:

```
ArrayReshape[sampleSpaces, {16, 2}]
```

and finally we delete duplicates as

```
DeleteDuplicates[ArrayReshape[sampleSpaces, {16, 2}]]
```

which yields

```
{{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}
```

and can be generalized, I think, in a straightforward manner.

Edit: you might find it useful to compare `sampleSpaces // Dimensions` to the number that you see in the `ArrayReshape` command.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There is hidden bug in the code. Tuples create all possible combinations include repeating one of the element, in above code if you change the range of i to 0 to 2 it will produce wrong answer.

Comment: @Parviz you need to make it more clear what it is that you want. At this stage I do not see why you do not just use something like `Tuples[{0,2},2]`. Please, update your question with this additional essential information.

Comment: As @CATrevillian mentioned `Tuples[{0,2},2]` is the most minimal and elegant way to approach. I only included the above as an answer, because it was too long for a comment. Also, when I mentioned that you could give a MWE before, I just meant that should explain in the OP with the original numbers you gave to give the expected result, so we can match it in mathematica. And as I mentioned in my comment, I think that `Tuples[{0, 1}, 3]` gives you what you are after -if I recall the first version of the O.P.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Problem with above solution is that, when I change the range of i {i,0,2}, I will have answer like {2 2 2}, which is not correct (j and k can not get 2 as the value).

Comment: Solution: Tuples[{Range[0, 3], Range[0, 4], Range[0, 8]}]